# wordpress custom api database search

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Car Rental plugin for wordpress. There is search form on the main page with these parameters:

- location from
- location to
- date from
- date to

On the other side, I'm developing system which interact with website.
What I need is to develop custom API which simulate search form, so, I need to pass these 4 parameters to api and get result from database.

I've started by adding add_action in functions.php of theme:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_route( 'my/price', '/getprice/(?P<id>\d+)', [
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_prices',
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
  ] );
} );

function get_prices( $request ) {
    $project = get_post( $request['id'] );
    return $project;
}
```

When I go to this addres: [www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/my/price/getprice/12](http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/my/price/getprice/12)
I'm getting this result:

```
{"ID":12,"post_author":"1","post_date":"2018-12-28 16:13:39","post_date_gmt":"2018-12-28 16:13:39","post_content":"[car_rental_system display=\"location\" location=\"1\"]\r\n[car_rental_system display=\"search\" location=\"1\" action_page=\"11\" steps=\"form,list,list,table,table\"]","post_title":"Hello world!","post_excerpt":"","post_status":"inherit","comment_status":"closed","ping_status":"closed","post_password":"","post_name":"1-revision-v1","to_ping":"","pinged":"","post_modified":"2018-12-28 16:13:39","post_modified_gmt":"2018-12-28 16:13:39","post_content_filtered":"","post_parent":1,"guid":"http:\/\/my.website\/2018\/12\/28\/1-revision-v1\/","menu_order":0,"post_type":"revision","post_mime_type":"","comment_count":"0","filter":"raw"}
```

I dont't know what I'm getting as results but, what I need is to simulate search process from the main page.

I need advice what approach should I use.

Comment: You got a post by its ID (12) as the result. What's the problem?